# What are the common uses for CAST function?

Tags: sql

What are the most common uses for CAST function in SQL?

I have only tried it in my google course the way they advised.

I am just trying to get a better understanding of how it works.

I am new to SQL and would love help from more seasoned Analyst.

Comment: "The CAST() function converts a value (of any type) into a specified datatype." - There is also CONVERT()

Comment: There's no CONVERT in standard SQL. Using cast is too often often indicates inconsistent table design.

Answer (score 0):

`CAST` is a function in SQL that can convert one data type into another. You can use it in various situations when you want to interpret one data type as another.

For example you have some data stored as `'123'` (123 as String/varchar), and you want to get the field as another type, let's say integer for this purpose. You would do:

```
SELECT CAST('123' AS INT) AS IntegerValue;
```

This is just for some value, for instance. You can use fields, you can compare data with it, cast and parse different data structures into another, aggregate functions.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.